# How do you set 'theme-dark' in bqplot?

Tags: bqplot

How do you set a dark theme in bqplot in a jupyter notebook environment?

IE, https://github.com/bloomberg/bqplot/pull/296

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following in a jupyter cell:

```
%%javascript
document.body.classList.add('theme-dark')
```

To remove the dark theme and return to default (light) theme, replace `add` by `remove` to remove the css class of the dark theme.